# use shell parameter extension in Makefile

Tags: bash, shell, makefile

How can I use shell parameter extension in a Makefile?
I need to get the path to the leveldb database.

What I tried so far is in my `Makefile`:

```
$(shell db=$(locate leveldb/db.h); export LEVELDB_PATH=${db%%/include/leveldb/db.h})
LEVELDB_LIBS=-L$(LEVELDB_PATH) -I$(LEVELDB_PATH)/include -lleveldb
```

But `LEVELDB_PATH` is empty.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shell cannot export stuff into your Makefile. Try something like this instead.

```
db := $(shell locate leveldb/db.h)
LEVELDB_PATH:=$(patsubst %/include/leveldb/db.h,%,$(db))
```

... or, to spare the temp variable,

```
LEVELDB_PATH:=$(shell locate leveldb/db.h | sed 's%/include/leveldb/db.h$$%%')
```

**Edit**: Fix to use `$(patsubst)` instead of `$(subst)`, and double the dollar sign in the `sed` script.

Generally speaking, whatever goes on inside `$(shell ...)` happens in a subprocess, which (as ever) cannot modify its parent.  `make` sees the output of the function when it finishes, but not what happened during the execution of the shell commands.

Comment: first one yields e.g. `-I/home/volker/TID/databases/leveldb/include/leveldb/db.h/include` and second one give:`sed: -e expression #1, char 24: unterminated `s' command`

Comment: Looks like the `%` is making problems. Leaving it (and taking into account, that this might be a string in the middle of the path?!) it works.

Comment: Does it mean, that one can't use % in makefile?

Comment: No, the problem was unrelated to the percent sign.